# Need Excel Function to Manage Eyetracking Data

Tags: excel-formula, data-science-experience, eye-tracking

This is my first time using this, so I apologize if my title was too vague. I'm a researcher whose new to using eye-tracking in studies. Due to that fact, I messed up in programming and now my data may take months to be analyzed. I think a good excel function could help me, I'm here for your advice.

Basically, I need a function that can search along a row (20 columns) for a value A. Value A is in a specific column (lets call it column A) that is tied to column B (20 possible options). Column B contains value B, the value I am interested in.

A few complicating factors:

- Value A is a coordinate value. It is in brackets.
- There are 20 columns that possess a possible 'value A'
- Value B is in the form XXXX.jpg
- There are 20 columns that possess a possible 'XXXX.JPG'
- 'Column A is tied to column B'. In the eye-tracking program the values in column A and B are properties of the 'image resource'. Participants saw 20 images on the screen in a grid arrangement. Each images has its' own image resource. Column A refers to the position that an image appeared in and Column B refers to the specific image that appeared.

For example, Column A is called 'pos1_1' and  Column B is called 'image1_1'

More in depth explanation...

- The function should be able to search along the row (for 20 columns (Z2 - AS2)) to find a coordinate. E.g. (240.0,108.0)
- Identify the column that this coordinate is in. E.g column **pos1_1**
- Identify the value in the same row in another column (F2 - Y2). Continuing this example, column **image1_1** (this column will always have the same numbers as the 'pos' column).

So if the function searches along row 2 (columns Z2 - AS2) and finds (240.0,108.0) in AJ2 then it should identify name in cell AJ1. For example,'pos1_1'. Then it should search along row 1 (columns F1 - Y1) to find 'image1_1' and produce the value in AJ2, 'XXXXX.jpg'

Does anyone have any ideas about where I could start? I'm thinking LOOKUP but it's giving me some trouble. I think because of the brackets around the values in the 'pos' column.

Comment: So give some samples and expected results and your current lookup formula you tried.

Answer (score 0):

i think i get you right but in case not so then let me know .

```
Function FindValue(searchValue As String) As String
    Dim coordinate As String
    Dim imageColumn As String
    Dim posColumn As String
    
    ' Loop through each row in the range
    For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        ' Check if the cell value contains the search value
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, searchValue) > 0 Then
            ' Get the coordinate value
            coordinate = cell.Value
            
            ' Get the corresponding image column
            imageColumn = "image" & Mid(coordinate, 2, Len(coordinate) - 2)
            
            ' Get the corresponding pos column
            posColumn = "pos" & Mid(coordinate, 2, Len(coordinate) - 2)
            
            ' Return the image column value
            FindValue = Cells(cell.Row, Range(imageColumn & "1").Column).Value
            
            ' Exit the function or can be customize if you want
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' If the search value is null, return an empty str. or else...
    FindValue = ""
End Function
```

in any cell, enter the following formula: =FindValue("[coordinate_value]"), here replace [coordinate_value] with the specific coordinate value you want to search for (e.g., (240.0,108.0) or what ever you want).
then press enter to get the corresponding image value in the tied column.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, this couldn't have been easy. That said, I have a few questions: I should've mentioned this in my initial post but there are 20 image columns (eg. image1_1, image2_1,image3_1..etc) and 20 position columns (eg. pos1_1, pos2_1, pos3_1, etc) , does this function account for that? From the little that I can understand the function looks good but I'm having a problem getting it to work.

Comment: well it is little surprise , so pleas update your question .

Comment: did you tried it ?

Comment: I tried it, but it just returned a blank. I just updated my question, hopefully, that helps.

Comment: can you provide sheet , for representation need not to be the real one, so that function can be written for that specially

Comment: How do I provide it? Do you have an email I can send it to?

Comment: you can just attack it's screen shot in your question

Comment: I've attached a link to an html website

Comment: well the file path can be be access by you on your computer , i dot know why you did that , [new-image-upload-support](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/)

Comment: My bad, I tried the link because the website isn't allowing me to upload pictures (I don't have enough participation points on the platform). Is there another way I could get you a representation?

Comment: just upload it to [here](http://imgur.com/) and share the hosting link. i feel you are new and will try my best to be friendly .

Comment: I am, thank you! Here is the link: https://imgur.com/a/qu38aeN

Comment: Hey, ...is this not possible?